# Pandas DataFrame: modify single values in the complete DataFrame, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like the following

```
      A        B    C

0     5 4)     0    3 2)
1     1        9    1
2     0,10 3)  9    0,22 3)
3     0.5      10   0.2
4     0,07 2)  2    0,05 3)
```

Now i want to change the values, that contain a bracket ")" so that only the first number remains. Like this:

```
      A        B    C

0     5        0    3 
1     1        9    1
2     0,10     9    0,22 
3     0.5      10   0.2
4     0,07     2    0,05
```

I tried it with the following code, which was sucessful.

```
for i in df["A"]:
    if ")" in str(i):
        new, filler = str(i).split(" ",1)
        df.replace(i, new,inplace=True)
```

Due to the large quantity of data, i need to do this operation on the whole DataFrame and not only on column "A". What is the best way to this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use for idx, values in df.iteritems(): then you aply thransformation invalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to split on the spaces and keep the first element of the resulting lists:

```
cols = ['A', 'C']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').str[0])
```

---

```
print(df)
A   B     C
0     5   0     3
1     1   9     1
2  0,10   9  0,22
3   0.5  10   0.2
4  0,07   2  0,05
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, if i use your code, I get a "NaN" for all the values, that don't contain ")". like this: A [ 5, NaN, 0.10, NAN, 0.07]

Comment: Okay my bad. I had the wrong type (float instead of str) in a few cells. With this change it worked: df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split(' ').str[0])     -Thank you!